Add a new filter in sort "Available for purchase" in magento 2.4.6
I want to add a new filter added in "Sort" that will show all items that you are able to add to your cart and purchase.we have a good amount of items that can not be purchased online be we do showcase.Need to add a filter called "available for purchase" and add it in the SORT filter.

Check this solution :
Add custom category filter in PLP page in Magento 2.4
Or you can create a custom attribute and add it to the product, making it filterable. The results will be added to the filter options.
